# Changing the Image when I select a new Image from files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am choosing a image using **input type = "file"**. But I am hiding the **choose file button** and showing a image instead of that. So when the user clicks on Image, the file options open.

Here is my code for that

```
   <div class="image-get">
                    <label for = "LoadImage">
                      <span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">
                       <img id="PreviewImage" align="left">
                       </span>
                    </label>
                   <input type="file" name="LoadImage" id="LoadImage" data-bind="value: LoadImage, hasfocus: LoadImage.focused">

           </div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
.image-get > input
{
display: none;
}

.image-get img
{
 width: 80px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

Here is the js code for showing the image when focus is lost

```
   self.LoadImage.focused = ko.observable();

   self.LoadImage.focused.subscribe(
  function(newValue) {



              if (!newValue)
              {
                    //alert("yupppiiieeee");

                     var reader = new FileReader();


                     reader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("LoadImage").files[0]);


                        reader.onload = function (Event)
                        {

                         //var source = src;
                         document.getElementById("PreviewImage").src = Event.target.result;


                        };


              }

 })
```

I think the problem is because of **display : none** but I am not sure. If I remove that, the choose file option shows which I don't want to show.
Any advice on how to achieve it. Thank You

Comment: It is unclear what is not working, also, posting a minimal working code snippet is recommended.

Comment: Is requirement to use `knockoutjs`?

Comment: _"Here is the js code for showing the image when focus is lost"_ When focus is lost on which element?

Comment: When Focus is lost on file element, the image shows

Comment: I am working on durandal project therefore knockout......

Comment: @LGSon   Actually, I want to show the new selected image in place of the old image, like a preview. But my preview is not coming.

Comment: Do you mean clicking on the image that should popup the file input dialog doesn't work but the default "Choose file" does?

Comment: Clicking on Image gets me the popup , but after selecting the image from file input dialog I want to show it to user, that does not work.

Comment: Is the `Event.target.result` a valid path to your image? ... Like: `http://www.yourdomain.com/images/uploaded.jpg` or `images/uploaded.jpg`

Comment: Yes, I have already checked that.... It is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correct, that it works without setting `display: none` on your input field, just change its CSS to this

```
.image-get > input
{
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
```

Comment: I will try this and let you Know. Thank You for the swift replies. :)

Comment: Thank You so much LGSon. It works, though it does not override whatever image I have in span, but I will figure that out. Again thank you for the swift replies.